# Ubuntu startup script

Tags: xubuntu

Is there a way to look at the script of things that Xubuntu does when it starts up?

Also to see the error logs it generates?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The standard locations for startup scripts are:

```
/etc/rc#.d/
```

or

```
/etc/rc.d/rc#.d
```

Where `#` is the runlevel that the system starts into.  On the later versions of Ubuntu the startup services are in:

```
/etc/init/
```

directory.

Now the logs for the startup would normally go into one or all of the following files:

```
/var/log/daemon.log
/var/log/syslog
/var/log/dmesg
/var/log/messages
```